# How to know the command that was run in PHP?

Tags: php, command-line

How to get the cli command that was run, from PHP?

I have this logging class

```
class Logger {

  public function log($logMessage)
  {
      $this->writeLog($this->getCommand() . ' : ' . $logMessage);
  }

  private function getCommand()
  {
      //How to get the command?
      //here  var_dump($argv); returns NULL
  }
}
```

This logger is being used by many classes that are run from several commands.
Tow examples:
**process_users.php**

```
$logger = new Logger();
$users = new Users();
foreach ($users->getUnprocessed() as $user) {
    $logger->log('processing '.$user->getId());
    if ($user->process()){
        $logger->log('processed ' . $user->getId());
    } else {
        $logger->log('failed ' . $user->getId());
    }
}
```

**upload_consumer.php**

```
$logger = new Logger();
$consumer = new UploadConsumer();

while ($message = $consumer->getNextMessage()){
    $logger->log('Uploading ' . $message['name']);
    $this->upload($message);
    $logger->log('Finished uploading '. $message['name']);
}
```

So when I run **php process_users.php corporate --limit 10**
I want to have logs like:

```
php process_users.php corporate --limit 10 : processing 2554
php process_users.php corporate --limit 10 : processed 2554 
php process_users.php corporate --limit 10 : processing 2555 
php process_users.php corporate --limit 10 : failed 2555
```

And when I run **php upload_consumer.php -m 100 -w**
I want to have logs like:

```
php upload_consumer.php -m 100 -w : Uploading 564sdf564sdf56sd4f.png
php upload_consumer.php -m 100 -w : Finished uploading  564sdf564sdf56sd4f.png 
php upload_consumer.php -m 100 -w : Uploading sd56f4sd54f6sd6f54.png
php upload_consumer.php -m 100 -w : Finished uploading  sd56f4sd54f6sd6f54.png
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$argv` which will give you the arguments passed to the script and the script name try var_dump($argv); so you can see what data you're working with.

More info here http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

You can also use getopt() if you just want the cli arguments and not the script name

Remember when using within a class or a function then you will have to do `global $argv` to bring it within the scope of the class or the function.  Alternatively you can pass it in as a parameter rather than using global.

Comment: what does $argc return ? if its zero then there's no options being passed to your script.  Failing that use the getopt() to parse them out manually from what you're expecting.  Both argc and getopt() should after a fashion give you what you're after.  What I'm not sure about (if its even a factor?) would be the usage of argc within a class you may have to generate it as a variable in the construct rather than in method because its system wide it should still be in scope within the class I believe.  Create a test page to check it is actually working when non-classed.

Comment: Found the solution, had to `global $argv` before using it. Please add this mention to your answer because it it actually 50% of the solution.

Comment: ahh cool so it was just a scoping issue.  Would have thought with it being system wide it would have been in scope within a class but meh... learn something new every day :)